# gulp-concat - вставка js-кода в уже имеющийся

Tags: jquery, gulp

Возникла потребность вставить код jquery в обертку:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <код>
})
```

В принципе, все это возможно сделать через порядок конкатенации, где первый и последний файл будут иметь строки этой функции:

```
gulp.task('concat-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['path/jquery-a.js', 'myscripts/**/*.js', 'path/jquery-a.js'])
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js'));
})
```

Где:

```
/jquery-a.js
$(document).ready(function(){

/jquery-b.js
})
```

Очевидно, что это ужаснейший велосипед и должно быть какое-либо рациональное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось достаточно легко, даже смешно:

Устанавливаем [gulp-insert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-insert) и делаем таск:

```
gulp.task('jquerry-wrap', function() {
    return gulp.src('<файл в который надо добавить обертку>')
    .pipe(insert.wrap('$(document).ready(function(){', '})'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('<директория с тем же файлом>'));
})
```